# What is the group structure behind quark color charge?

Tags: group-theory, modules, physics, quotient-group

Suppose you take the free $\mathbb Z$-module with two generators $\{P,N\}$ and quotient out by the relation $P+N = 0$. You get a one-dimensional module that has two additively independent elements $P$ and $-P$. By additive independence I mean you cannot write any one element as a linear combination of the others with positive coefficients.
The two independent elements correspond to the two types of electromagnetic charge, positive and negative.

If instead we start with three generators $\{R,B,G\}$ and quotient out by $R+B+G$ we get a structure that models the three types of color charge and their negatives for quarks. Like everyone knows, each quark can have red, blue, green, antired, antiblue, or antigreen charge. But they only occur in pairs of three, one of each color, which compose a particle with neutral color charge.

Here the elements $-R,-B,-G$ are the antired, antiblue, and antigreen charges. The relation red + blue = antigreen comes out of the relation $R+B+G= 0$ when we subtract $G$ from both sides. This time there are six additively independent elements.

In general suppose we start with the module generated by $\{g_1,\ldots, g_n\}$ and quotient out by $g_1+\ldots+ g_n=0$. What is the additive dimension of the quotient module?

Comment: Does "module" mean abelian group?  Is your ring $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, module over $\mathbb Z$ thanks.

Comment: The quotient in your last paragraph is just a free abelian group on $n-1$ generators. Personally I would say it has "additive dimension" $2(n-1)$, but you apparently find $6$ when $n=3$, so clearly I have not really understood what this "dimension" is. In any case, you can forget about the quotient and just think about a free abelian group of rank $n-1$ if you want.

Comment: What color is antigreen? Purple?

Comment: @markvs It is sometimes drawn as magenta.

Comment: @CaptainLama I am not sure what I am asking myself. Only that there are two types of charges and three types of color charges, and the structures seem to have a similar quotient involved.

Comment: Are you trying to bypass SU(3) for which this R,B,G stuff serve as clumsy popular science journalism confusing stand-ins?